# Python-3.x: How to print multiple lists in equal columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm quite new to python,I am trying to output multiple lists, one under the other, in columns, and I have no idea.

My current output is:

```
Name, Count, Correct, Incorrect, Accuracy, Total

Abena 3 3 0 100 45

Malcolm 1 1 0 100 1

Jane 1 1 0 100 20

Liz 1 1 0 100 10

Andy 1 0 1 0 20

Sandip 0 0 0 0 0
```

How do I separate the numbers into separate columns?

Current code to print is:

```
CoinFile = open("CoinCount.txt", "r")
    print("Name, Count, Correct, Incorrect, Accuracy, Total")
    for record in VolunteersToSort:
            print(record[0] + " " + record[1]+ " " + record[2] + " " + record[3] + " " + record[4] + " " + record[5] )
```

The contents of the file:

```
['Abena', '3', '3', '0', '100', '45']
['Malcolm', '1', '1', '0', '100', '1']
['Jane', '1', '1', '0', '100', '20']
['Andy', '1', '0', '1', '0', '20']
['Sandip', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['Liz', '1', '1', '0', '100', '10']
```

Comment: Can you please add expected output also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
header = ['Name', 'Count', 'Correct', 'Incorrect', 'Accuracy', 'Total']
my_list = [
    ['Abena', '3', '3', '0', '100', '45'], 
    ['Malcolm', '1', '1', '0', '100', '1'],
    ['Jane', '1', '1', '0', '100', '20'],
    ['Andy', '1', '0', '1', '0', '20'],
    ['Sandip', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
    ['Liz', '1', '1', '0', '100', '10']
]    
print("{: >10} {: >10} {: >10} {: >10} {: >10} {: >10}".format(*header))
for row in my_list:
    print("{: >10} {: >10} {: >10} {: >10} {: >10} {: >10}".format(*row))
```

You will have output as:

```
      Name      Count    Correct  Incorrect   Accuracy      Total 
     Abena          3          3          0        100         45 
   Malcolm          1          1          0        100          1 
      Jane          1          1          0        100         20 
      Andy          1          0          1          0         20 
    Sandip          0          0          0          0          0 
       Liz          1          1          0        100         10
```

You can edit column length as you need. Here 10 is used.

Comment: Sorry for not responding with my expected output earlier, this is perfect and exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading from file which has data in comma separated. you can use below code.

```
with open("file.txt") as x :
    for w in x :
        print(" ".join(["{:10s}".format(i) for i in w.rstrip('\n').split(',')]))
```

output:

```
Name       Count      Correct    Incorrect  Accuracy   Total     
Abena      3          3          0          100        45        
Malcolm    1          1          0          100        1         
Jane       1          1          0          100        20        
Andy       1          0          1          0          20        
Sandip     0          0          0          0          0         
Liz        1          1          0          100        10
```